# How to sync files directly to a shared drive in google drive using google drive for desktop or any other software?

Tags: google-drive-file-stream

Currently, google **drive for desktop** app syncs files on my computer tab in google drive, which takes my own cloud space. So is it possible to sync my files directly to a shared drive? For example, I want to backup my full D: drive to a shared drive.

**What I am looking for is a way to directly sync my files to a shared drive on google drive.**

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive at drive.google.com have up to three tabs for file stores:

- My Drive,
- Computers and
- Shared Drives.

In order to be able to use Shared Drive you should have access to use feature either by using a Google Workspace account having authoization to create new shared drives or if someone shared with your account a Shared Drive. In order to be able to add files to a Shared Drive, you should have the respective permission.

If your files are on the local D: drive are being synced to Computers but you want to sync them to Shared Drives, by using Drive for Desktop as is provided by Google, you have you move those files from this local drive to one of the shared drives. This could be done by doing the regular operations to move files from one location to another by using the file management system of your computer.

Before moving a lot of files, please review very carefully

1. how Drive for Desktop works,
2. that your computer have enough free space.

Warning: If you do not really understand how the file storage elements works do not try to move a large number of files (thousands ) or a set of files that takes a lot of space (hundreds of GBs) at once as if an error happens some files might lost.

Also I think that you should contact your Google Drive administrator and network administrator so they don't be surprised if suddenly they see unusual activity alerts on their dashboards.

---

Note: According to https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2021/07/google-drive-backup-and-sync-transition.html, Backup and Sync users should transition to Drive for Desktop.

Comment: To clarify I am using Drive for Desktop. You are saying that I can move the files from my computer but isn't it possible to sync my files directly to the shared drive?

Comment: Regarding the clarification, please update the question. Regarding the second part, if you are looking for "hacky" solutions, also, update the questions to clarify what kind of solution you are looking for including details about name and version of your operative system and brief description of you search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hello. I have updated my question as required.